# Generating Create & Insert Script using TOAD at once for an oracle db

Tags: oracle, toad

we have a DB with lots of tables related to our application (not all ), views, triggers, functions, procedures etc.

Is there any way to generate script to create those objects in another DB + insert statements.

We don't want to take DB backup as it has lot other things.

please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

you could use DBMS_METADATA to extract the DDL

oryou could use SQL Developer Tools->Database Export

in Toad you can use Database->Export->Export DDL